# Modal doesn't pop out

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, allow-modals

I am a newbie in the field of web-development. Below picture is of my website's homepage. Here's what i'm trying to do

[image: pic 1]

On clicking the user login  it is redirected to login page[image: login]

Now, issue is whenever i click on **forgot password** link forgot password modal doesn't pop up, however it's address is being shown in http section.
[image]

Here's my script:
**View Login**

```
 <?php echo form_open("validate/login");?> 

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">UserID</label>
            <input type="email" id="txt_username" name="user_email" class="form-control styled" placeholder="Enter your Username">
             <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('user_email'); ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="txt_password" name="txt_password" class="form-control styled" placeholder="Enter your Password">
             <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('txt_password'); ?></span>
          </div>
       <div>
      <left> <input type="hidden" name="rmShown" value="1">                                      
        <a id="link-forgot-passwd" class="need-help" href="#myModalForgot" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalForgot">Forgot password? </a></left>
        </div>

         <center><input type="submit" name="btn_login" class="btn btn-styled" value="Login"></center><br>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Modal**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalForgot" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="password-modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Reset Your Password</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


      <center>

          <h3> Kindly provide us with your email account so we can send you the link to reset your password. </h3>
      </center>



        <?php echo form_open("validate/forgot");?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter your email address ">
        </div>


         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-styled2">Reset Password</button>
        </div>
       <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**view Home**

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <!-- <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/validate/login">Login</a></li> -->
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Login<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/validate/login/">User Login</a></li>

        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Admin">Admin Login</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Please suggest what i'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time. Any kind of help would be appreciated.